# How to use lighthouse with login details?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, jwt, lighthouse

I have tried the below script for generating lighthouse reports it is working fine for login page and not working for pages after authentication.

```
@For /F "UseBackQ Delims=" %%A In ("./urls.txt"
) Do @LightHouse "%%A"   lighthouse --emulated-form-factor=desktop  --quiet --chrome-flags="--headless" --extra-headers=./headers.json --throttling-method=provided  --disable-storage-reset=false "disableDeviceEmulation": "true" --view ----output-path "C:\Users\sujith\Desktop\test.html" --only-categories=performance,accessibility
```

I have tried passing token in headers.json as follows but it doesn't work.

```
{
  "access-key": "value;"
}
```

Is there any issue in urls(insecure)?

```
   http://localhost:3000/#/
   http://localhost:3000/#/collections
   http://localhost:3000/#/home
```

Comment: Describe your authentication process

Comment: I have to pass the jwt. can i know the proper syntax.

Comment: token gets generated once i login and it's stored in local storage.

Comment: How to give local storage key,value pair(token) in headers.json.

Comment: when i use chrome devtools it is working fine. But i need to automate it by above script.